# ODBC/JDBC proxy to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, proxy, odbc

I've heard of a tool allowing to expose an ODBC/JDBC compliant database as a Postgesql database.

It was an opensource project on GitHub or Sourceforge. I'm unable to remember it or find it in my bookmarks.

Any clue ?

Comment: So, a tool would automatically transform any database into PostgreSQL? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: No, it transforms only the underlying protocol on the wire (it allows for a client not ODBC nor JDBC enabled [but able to connect to postgres, ie by using libpq for example] to connect to the ODBC/JDBC database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you need this because you have a pglib based legacy application.

In that case a work around might be to set up a gateway postgresql database, and then use the foreign server capability to connect via ODBC to the real target database.

You application would then talk to the gateway database via pglib, which would then in turn delegate the query down to the real database.

[ODBC foreign data wrapper](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers)

[Postgresql 9.1 documentation on creating a foreign server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-createserver.html)

Comment: Didn't know about that feature. Very handy, thank you Gary. Accepted !